# Where to buy "Medalla"?

Tags: local, buying, cans

Where can I order Puerto Rican brand "Medalla" (canned) from Germany/online ?

May there is better German beer available, but I liked drinking frozen Medalla when I was visiting PR last summer - and right now it's hot in Germany and I really miss it...

Comment: FYI, a few weeks ago I gave this a good hour of research and even called a few places, to no avail. Good luck, and if you ever find some please come back to let us know where.

Answer (score 2):

Call them and find out cause in NYC you can get it at a couple of international beer carriers (SEARCH ON YELP).

Or try PRESIDENTE Beer from their DR neighbours at any Publix Supermarket/Wine & Spirits.

[Phone Number to Medalla Company](http://www.diffordsguide.com/beer-wine-spirits/beer-cider-and-perry/lager-bottom-fermented/BWS002325/medalla-light)